# Check the differentiability of the function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

**Question** Check the differentiability of the function f$\left(x,y\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \left(x,y\right)\neq\left(0,0\right)\\
0 & otherwise,
\end{cases}$

**My Approach** I know a function of two variable is differentiable
at $\left(a,b\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow$
f$\left(a+h,b+k\right)-f\left(a,b\right)=Ah$$+Bk+\phi\left(h,k\right)\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}},where$
A=$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ =$f_{x}$=0 ,B=$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$=$f_{y}=0$
and $\phi\left(h,k\right)$$\longrightarrow0$ as$\left(h,k\right)\longrightarrow\left(0,0\right)$.

$f$$\left(a+h,b+k\right)-f\left(a,b\right)=$$\phi\left(h,k\right)\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}$$\Longrightarrow$$\phi\left(h,k\right)\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}=\frac{2h^{2}k}{h^{2}+k^{2}}$

taking h=rcos$\theta$ and 
 k=rsin$\theta$$\Longrightarrow$$\phi\left(h,k\right)=2cos^{2}\theta$$sin\theta$$\neq$0
$\forall$$\theta$$\Longrightarrow$ $\phi\left(h,k\right)$do not
tend to 0 as$\left(h,k\right)\longrightarrow\left(0,0\right)$.So
function is not differentiable at origin

**BOOK's Approach** A function of two variable is differentiable at
$\left(a,b\right)$ $\Leftrightarrow$f$\left(a+h,b+k\right)-f\left(a,b\right)=Ah$$+Bk+\psi\left(h,k\right)h+\xi\left(h,k\right)k$
(i know this is equivalent to mine rule)

$\frac{2h^{2}k}{h^{2}+k^{2}}=$h$\left(\frac{hk}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\right)+k\left(\frac{h^{2}}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\right)$$\Longrightarrow$$\psi\left(h,k\right)=$$\left(\frac{hk}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\right)$and
$\xi\left(h,k\right)$=$\left(\frac{h^{2}}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\right)$

Book says as$\left(h,k\right)\rightarrow\left(0,0\right)$$\psi$and
$\xi$ also go to $0$.So Function is differentiable at origin.Book uses the word h and k tends to zero simultaneously.

But,Lim$_{\left(h,k\right)\longrightarrow\left(0,0\right)}\psi\left(h,k\right)$and
Lim$_{\left(h,k\right)\longrightarrow\left(0,0\right)}\xi\left(h,k\right)$
do not exist.

Please tell me if book is right , then where i was wrong in my approach.It
would be very helpful if the posted answers use my approach and go
further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

It is clear that ${\partial f(0,0) \over \partial x} = {\partial f(0,0) \over \partial y} = 0 $.

Consider $\lim_{t \to 0} {f(t,t) - f(0,0) \over t} = 1$. If $f$ was
differentiable at $(0,0)$ then this limit would
be ${\partial f(0,0) \over \partial x} 1 +  {\partial f(0,0) \over \partial y} 1 = 0$.

Comment: It is not only about solving the question.I want to know where i am wrong in my approach and why book is not wrong even when limits do not exist

Comment: My previous answer was incorrect.

Comment: I am very happy right now, because I couldn't sleep properly throughout the night.It is very shameful that books make that kind of  huge mistakes.

Comment: @MohanSharma: Everyone is human :-).